# how to login with facebook with custom login button using facebook sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

As per developers.facebook.com, I made a demo for Facebook login, but they automatically give their `login button` with `signin` written on it. How to use our custom button as `login button`?

Comment: read the guide, again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it with code below. Put that **Facebook** `FBlogin` Button in place of your button and set your own image using following code. **You just set frame and use your own image of FBloginButton but you can not set custom IBAction of this following fbLogin Button**:

```
if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {

    loginview =
            [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithPublishPermissions:@[@"email"] defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone];


}


loginview.frame =FB_login.frame;//CGRectMake(90,149, 280, 55); // here set fbLoginview frame to your login Button Frame
        for (id obj in loginview.subviews)
        {
            if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
            {
                UIButton * loginButton =  obj;

                UIImage *loginImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_fb_login.png"];// here set your own image
                [loginButton setBackgroundImage:loginImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected];
                [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
                [loginButton sizeToFit];
            }
            if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
            {
                UILabel * loginLabel =  obj;
                loginLabel.text =@""; //@"Log in to facebook";
                loginLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
                loginLabel.frame =CGRectMake(123,149, 280, 55);// CGRectMake(0, 0, 271, 37);
            }
        }

        loginview.delegate = self;

        [self.view addSubview:loginview];
```